# CriteriaBuilder OffsetDateTime Comparison

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, criteria, criteria-api

I use Springboot, and I'd like to implement a "search" API for an entity that has an "OffsetDateTime" attribute.

The attribute is of type "OffsetDateTime" in my Hibernate entity :

```
@Column(name = "creation_date")
    private OffsetDateTime creationDate;
```

The attribute that I get from the API is of type "OffsetDateTime" too.

I use the Springboot Specification, with the OffsetDateTime value as criteria.getValue() :

```
@Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Job> root, CriteriaQuery<?> criteriaQuery, CriteriaBuilder builder) {
          return builder.equal(root.get("creationDate"), criteria.getValue());
    }
```

But the above code doesn't return me the entity with the specified date

However, the following code does :

```
@Override
        public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Job> root, CriteriaQuery<?> criteriaQuery, CriteriaBuilder builder) {
              Predicate predicate = builder.between(root.<OffsetDateTime>get("creationDate"),
                        ((OffsetDateTime) criteria.getValue()).minus(1, ChronoUnit.MILLIS),
                        ((OffsetDateTime) criteria.getValue()));
        }
```

In my DB I have "2020-03-12 17:25:11.047", and the value I pass to the API is "2020-03-12T17:25:11.047+01:00". I'm in France, so I have a 1 hour offset, and the time is saved as a local time in the db, but that doesn't seem to be the problem as the second solution does return the entity I want.

Do you know why the first solution doesn't return me the entity, and how I could get the entity without having to set a 1 millisecond interval ?